# How to send $_GET data as comma separated array

Tags: php, arrays, get

I'm stumped on something which feels like it should be simple. I have three `<select>` inputs which need their values in the query string like this when submitting the form;

`domain.com/?filter=one,two,three`

Is this possible? How should I structure the form `name` attributes? I was also wondering if I can get the `$_GET` values server side after submission and create the array myself and set this as the page's URL, but wouldn't that technically be a redirect?

Ideally this would be done with the query string so the URL can be copy and pasted or shared, it's not sensitive data either. Hopefully someone can help...some rough markup below;

```
<form action="get">
   <select name="filter[]"></select>
   <select name="filter[]"></select>
   <select name="filter[]"></select>
   <button type="submit>Submit</button>
</form>
```

..and there is a reason why all the `<option>` element are not in one `<select>`, it's not ideal, I know! Thanks

Comment: To my knowledge, there's no way to structure the `name` attributes on form elements to get a comma-separated list of values for one name. The syntax you're using with the brackets will result in a query string looking like `?filter[]=one&filter[]=two&filter[]=three`, and PHP should interpret that as an array. You can use JavaScript and a hidden input to convert to a comma-separated value if you want, but that won't work if JavaScript is disabled or not available.

Comment: @skeggse Thanks for the reply. I think jS could be the only way forward with this problem.

Answer (score 3):

I don't advice using this code snippet exactly, it merely exists to demonstrate a possible solution using JavaScript.

HTML:

```
<form action="get" id="myform">
  <input id="filter-result" name="filter" type="hidden">
  <input class="filter-value">
  <input class="filter-value">
  <input class="filter-value">
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
var slice = Array.prototype.slice;
var myform = document.querySelector("#myform");

myform.addEventListener('submit', function() {
  document.querySelector("#filter-result").value =
    slice.call(myform.querySelectorAll(".filter-value"))
    .map(function(input) {
      return input.value;
    }).join(',');
});
```

Notice that the filter-value inputs do not have a `name`, so they won't be included in the GET query string.

Comment: @Dan if this answer fixed your problem, or was sufficient to answer your question, please accept it by clicking the grey checkbox under the up/down votes. That way anyone with a similar problem can find the answer that helped you the most.